# Updating existing timeline posts using Facebook's Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, scrape

Is a POST to `graph.facebook.com/?id={id}&scrape=true` (as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/#update)) supposed to expire cache and update already-published timeline data immediately?

I have noticed in my case that when I update an og:image value for an Open Graph object page, enter the object's URL in the Facebook Debugger and then refresh my friend's Facebook timeline, I see the updated og:image immediately.

However, I do not see existing timeline open graph action publishes updated when using the `graph.facebook.com/?id={id}&scrape=true` method.  It seems like my POST to scrape is not working, but the response I get is a JSON with all the updated data I expect.
I also notice that any new timeline posts for the same object have the new og:image referenced immediately, so it seems like the scrape is working - but not updating existing posts.  Is there a way to force existing timeline posts to be updated as well, or is that working for others?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research, I seemed to have a race condition issue here.  Adding a delay to force the Facebook post a few seconds after persisting object changes fixed the issue for me.